# Nvidia Driver and Heating Problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, bumblebee, overheating

this is my first question at here, so please be gentle if do something wrong.

I have Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS installed on my laptop. Also i have working dual boot to Windows 10 with UEFI activated.

My laptop is warming up too much faster than Windows, tempature never downs below 65 C.

I search this problem a bit and i see posts about bumblebee Nvidia drivers etc. So i decide to install proper Nvidia drivers to use Nvidia GTX960m only when i choose.

For that i had to install Nvidia drivers first, but when i tried and reboot i cant pass the login screen. When i check xsession-erros file, i see some erros like that;

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

I had to remove all nvidia packages to correct this situation and login again. What am i doing wrong?

Also i'm open advices for any other choices. I just use Ubuntu for developing at Ruby; so i dont need to use Nvidia GTX960m really. I just want to keep my laptop cool ( make as much as ) and last longer at battery.

Thanks!

Ps: English is not my native language, if i spelled something wrong; i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below answer is only applicable if your laptop has nvidia Optimus:

I got my optimus laptop working with bumblebee/nvidia.
Temperature is ~48C idle

Basically you do this:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mamarley/nvidia
>
> sudo apt-get update

install bumblebee and the nvidia driver

> sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-352 nvidia-352-uvm nvidia-settings

then you need to sudo gedit /etc/modules and add

> i915
>
> bbswitch

then you need to sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
and make sure the line

> blacklist nvidia-352

is there, if not add it.

finally you need to sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

line 22: >Driver=nvidia

line 55: >KernelDriver=nvidia-352

line 58: >LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352:/usr/lib32/nvidia-352

line 61: >XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules

reboot.

This answer comes from:
http://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.gr/2015/05/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-driver-in.html

see there for more explanation.
It is approved by many (and me)to work, though the difference is that i don't use ppa:xorg-edgers (since it is unstable) and use ppa:mamarley/nvidia and ppa:bumblebee/stable, i recommend you do that instead.

Games run "almost" fine and i can use my both my cards simultaneously.

intel core i5-3210m, GT 650M

P.S what do you mean by "proper" nvidia drivers?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

But i was found my solution 2-3 days ago with doing format. After that i used xorg-edgers ppa and install nvidia 352 and prime to get it work. So far i get 48-49C when idle.

Thanks anyway!