# lightdm - Job failed to start (xorg problem?!) / bumblebee/cuda related?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, lightdm, bumblebee, cuda

*Please work through my wall of text, need help!! Thank you!*

Booting up my laptop this morning, I encountered the following problem:
Boot to black screen with no responsiveness, couldn't even get to `tty1` from there.

Then got to a console by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> on the boot-up splash with the Ubuntu logo and the dots, logged in and tried stopping/starting `lightdm` manually with the following error messages:

```
stop: Job has already been stopped: lightdm
start: Job failed to start
```

So I started digging into log files to try and figure out what is going wrong. `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` has the following lines:

```
DEBUG: Process 1754 terminated with signal 6
DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: X server stopped
DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
DEBUG: Seat: Display server stopped
DEBUG: Seat: Stopping; greeter display server failed to start
```

That ought to be an xorg problem somehow then, right? I checked **/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log**

```
Loading extension GLK
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
```

and in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` when it tries to (i assume) find the drivers, it is looking for intel, intel, modestting, fbdev, vesa - cannot open any and:

```
(EE) No drivers available.
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
```

I tried a lot of reinstalling / reconfiguring lightdm and trying out gdm, to no success - which makes sense given it seems to be a driver/display issue?!

So here is background on that: Yd, I installed **bumblebee** and **nvidia-352** and got it working for the first time. I did not boot to black screen and could configure bumblebee, such that glxsphere64 either uses the intel driver or the nvidia driver and card with optirun.

At that point, I installed, after a lot of installing/finding required packages, **CUDA 7.5** as well, tested it on the cuda-test deviceQuery and got the expected results. I then also installed matlab all before rebooting / shutting down. It is after this shutdown that the problems occured - so either something happened to the bumblebee config or the cuda install, yes? I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on, I am not very proficient at these tings..

`/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` points to the right places, I did manage to load up the nvidia card/driver with optirun so thats expected.

`/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` only has 1 unexpected line, it says:

```
VirtualDisplay=:8
```

and I cannot figure out if that is an expected entry here, don't wanna fiddle around with it though.

`sudo X -configure` tells me I have a missing output driver.

I tried removing the `Xorg.conf` files, with no results. bumblebee also is not loaded up on the limited boot-up I am getting, as I have no experience I do not know if that is expected. `sudo service bumblebee start` starts it no problem, but that does not solve any issues as far as I can see. `lsmod | grep nvidia` and `lsmod | grep nouveau` do not give any results, I should expect that as nouveau is not installed and the nvidia drivers should only be used for optirun apps, yea? `lsmod | grep i9` gives back `i915` as well as `video *stuff* i915` - that is the kernel driver for my onboard graphics unit, correct? With `lspci | grep VGA` it returns the Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller.

So, has anyone any clue what might be going wrong here?

Redoing the driver/bumblebee install is of course always an option - as it was such a hassle I am trying to avoid it in fear of not reproducing it or ending up at the same spot.

If I have to resort to it anyway: Do you think I can just keep the CUDA install? Will matlab figure out a newly installed graphics driver?

**Here is an update**:

I could not figure out anyway to fix this, so I reinstalled, went through the same steps to set up bumblebee and the nvidia-352 drivers - up to here it works! What is different is this: I did not explicitly install virtualgl and libraries so i cannot test with glxspheres64 for example - will that be problematic? What is the best ppa to add to install all that, its does not seem to be in the standard package? I also did not install cuda, I suspect that is where it went wrong! Does installing cuda via package manager and the 1.9GB Deb file also overwrite openGL stuff?

Comment: **Here is an update:** I could not figure out anyway to fix this, so I reinstalled, went through the same steps to set up bumblebee and the nvidia-352 drivers - up to here it works! What is different is this: I did not explicitly install virtualgl and libraries so i cannot test with glxspheres64 for example - will that be problematic? **What is the best ppa to add to install all that, its does not seem to be in the standard package?** I also did not install cuda, I suspect that is where it went wrong! Does installing cuda via package manager and the 1.9GB Deb file also overwrite openGL stuff?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm sounds like an nvidia-driver problem!

Can you uninstall cuda? maybe that is the problem.
Did you update before shutting down?
That may also be a problem!

The instructions come from here: [Nvidia Driver and Heating Problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660913/nvidia-driver-and-heating-problem/662662#662662)

In terminal:
remove CUDA (I don't know how)

reinstall bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-352 **nvidia-352-uvm** primus nvidia-cuda-toolkit libcuda1-352

With the **nvidia-352-uvm** package you actually have CUDA.

configure bumblebee like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

line 22: Driver=nvidia

line 55: KernelDriver=nvidia-352

line 58: LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352:/usr/lib32/nvidia-352

line 61: XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
```

blacklist it:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
```

make sure the line

```
blacklist nvidia-352
```

is there

Finally add the intel driver and bumblebee switch (bbswitch) to /etc/modules

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

add those lines:

```
i915
bbswitch
```

Then it should work alright.

Samsung NP550P5C S02 intel core i5-3210m+ Intel HD 4000, Geforce GT 650M

EDIT:

1 last thing:
You may need to run these commands to get cuda and blender working:

```
sudo modprobe nvidia-uvm //loads nvidia-uvm
sudo blender             // run blender as superuser, else it doesn't recognize it the first time (you dont need optirun/primusrun for cuda)
```

then select "CUDA" in the user preferences.. then close blender.

Afterwards for the rest of the day you can use blender cuda without sudo

Only do this if it doesnt work Out-Of-The-Box

Comment: As mentioned up top, I reinstalled everything up to CUDA and it works for now - so the CUDA install is where i have to becareful! I will try adding the blacklist and modules lines before I go ahead and then install 352-uvm with the cuda toolkit and libcuda before and then report back :) Thanks already!

Comment: don't install CUDA from .run

Comment: i downloaded the .deb local repo and installed that way - dont think it promted me for a driver install and from what i can gather that is where openGL stuff may be overwritten.

Comment: you don't have to install anything outside ubuntu repositories to get CUDA, installing everything above is OK.

Comment: i have it working mostly now, setting up cuda correctly will still take some time/research so i can use it in matlab! thank you very much for the tips!