# Why Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is working slow in my system while Windows 10 is performing much faster than this?

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, graphics, windows-10

I have Dell laptop and one week ago I replaced Windows 10 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Ubuntu is working slow on my system i.e. in booting, shutdown, opening any application.
My system specifications are:

- 8 GB RAM
- 1 TB HDD
- 2 GB Graphic Card (Nvidia-Geforce)

In windows, I had played lots of higher graphics games and it had been supported by system; but in Ubuntu, a Chromium browser taking time to load.

Comment: First make a clean install of ubuntu again, than make sure you have installed proper drivers for the specs your pc has. and are you sure you have installed amd64 version?

Answer (score 0):

As biozalp mentioned you should make sure you have the 64-bit version
check with

```
System Settings->Details->OS Type
```

You should install the 64-bit version, if it shows you have the 32-bit one

it's very probable that you have nvidia optimus!
check with the below terminal command, its shows all your graphics cards on the system:

```
lspci | grep VGA|3D
```

If it shows 2 graphics cards, then you have nvidia optimus.

if you have Nvidia Optimus: then you should follow the below instructions to install the drivers properly in the answer here!:
[Nvidia Driver and Heating Problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660913/nvidia-driver-and-heating-problem/662662#662662)

Answer (score 0):

Check your enabled services and disable those you don't use. You can use tools for checking services like sysv-rc-conf or use the update-rc.d command.

Regards,

Comment: A clean install should not work "slow". I doubt if this answer will be of any help to the OP without guidance on what he should disable.

Comment: Without knowing what services are running you can't recommend what to disable. And it will depend on what services he needs, therefore I suggested him to check all services and disable those he considers not in used. But the way I didn't recommend a clean install.

Comment: He just installed the system a week ago, so that is pretty clean. You indeed do not know what is running but a fresh system with the described specs should just run smoothly and does not need lowering in resources.